# How do I suppress the value of #VALUE! in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

How do I write this into the formula to make the #VALUE! blank?

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B10,Claims!$A$1:$G$18591,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP($B10,Claims!$A$1:$G$18591,2,0))/1000
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious too - is that formula actually correct? That's a lot of errors...

Comment: I cannot tell you as it was written by the original author and some of the things he did was like - eh?? But it did work, just made the spreadsheet look obnoxious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when the VLOOKUP returns an error you are trying to divide a null string by 1000.

So add the division into the check:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B10,Claims!$A$1:$G$18591,2,0)/1000),"",VLOOKUP($B10,Claims!$A$1:$G$18591,2,0)/1000)
```

But, there is no need for the use of ISERROR, wrap in IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B10,Claims!$A$1:$G$18591,2,0)/1000,"")
```

It avoids the need of duplicate enteries.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! THANK YOU!!!! yeah it was a formula written from the original author that I took over the report from and some of the things he wrote confused the heck out of me and I am streamlining some of the silliness there....:)